# Does Not Implement Interface in sportsstore asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, interface, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm following on asp.net mvc 5 book by apress and I've got stuck at one point with this error:

> "SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.EFProductRepository' does not implement
> interface member
> 'SportsStore.Domain.Abstract.IProductRepository.Products.set"

This is what I have in EFProductRepository:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        public EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return context.Products; }
        }       
    }
}
```

And in IProductRepository I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting the error in EFProductRepository.cs class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're not implementing a setter for the property.  Look at the interface's definition:

```
IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

And look at your implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> Products
{
    get { return context.Products; }
}
```

You need to either implement a `set` in the property, or remove `set` from the interface definition.  Given the implementation of the property, I'm guessing the latter is more appropriate.

---

If it helps, since it looks like you're building a repository for Entity Framework objects, here's what one of mine generally looks like:

```
public interface ProductRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    void Add(Product model);
    void Remove(Product model);
}
```

and the implementation:

```
public class ProductRepositoryImplementation : ProductRepository
{
    private DbSet<Product> _products;

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get { return _products; }
    }

    public ProductRepositoryImplementation(DbSet<Product> products)
    {
        _products = products;
    }

    public void Add(Product model)
    {
        _products.Add(model);
    }

    public void Remove(Product model)
    {
        _products.Remove(model);
    }
}
```

Generally this is housed within a unit of work object, which extends `DbContext` and handles committing the changes to its repositories.  (That's also what passes the `DbSet<>` to the constructor for the repositories.)  I actually [just blogged](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/persistence-ignorance-with-entity.html) about this setup today.

Answer (score 2):

The error seems pretty clear - you need to either add a `set` accessor to your property or remove it from the interface.  In your case it probably makes more sense to remove it from the interface:

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; /*set;*/ }
    }
}
```

Adding entities to a repository via a `set` accessor doesn't seem proper - usually a repository has a `Save` or `Update` method that works on one entity at a time.